# Configuration change to make all searchs case insensitive

Tags: emacs

Hopefully, an easy question.

I want all searches, or at least isearch-repeat-foward to be case insensitive w/o having to hit M-c.

Looking for the correct function call or variable to set in my .emacs file to turn case insensitivity on at the start of Emacs.

I know the regex search in case insensitive, but I want normal search to be insensitive.

Tried setting, (setq case-fold-search 1), that didn't work. I'm new to Emacs be gentle.

Comment: Why are you calling `isearch-repeat-forward`? You shouldn't have to do this, it is called automatically from within `isearch-forward`. It's also case-insensitive by default.

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be case insensitive, but it's not for me. Probably caused by some other library I foolishly loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant vars are:

```
(setq search-upper-case nil)
(setq isearch-case-fold-search 'yes)
```

It's up to you if you want to set them. I'm happy with the defaults.